# Insert elements from one array to another after each 'n' index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Native JS.
Have 2 arrays, for example

```
arr1 = ['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'white', 'magenta', 'cyan']
arr2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

I need a function, that combine this 2 arrays, like this

```
function arrInsertAfter(arr1, arr2, afterElement) 
// for example make afterElement = 2 - insert element of second array after each 2 elements of first array

....
```

And result should be

```
['orange', 'blue', 1, 'red', 'black', 2, 'white', 'magenta', 3, 'cyan']
```

If `afterElement = 3` for example it should return

```
['orange', 'blue', 'red', 1, 'black', 'white', 'magenta', 2, 'cyan', 3] // append remaining elements of second array at the end simply
```

It's important to not use any third-party connected lib's.

Here is my function

```
let arr1 = ['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'white', 'magenta', 'cyan'],
        arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

function arrInsertAfter(arr1, arr2, afterElement) {

        let curPos = afterElement;

        arr2.forEach(function(e) {
            arr1.splice(curPos, 0, e);
            curPos = afterElement+curPos+1;
        });

        return arr1;

    }
```

With traditional loop

```
  function arrInsertAfter(arr1, arr2, afterElement) {

    let curPos = afterElement;

      for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        arr1.splice(curPos, 0, arr2[i]);
        curPos = (curPos+afterElement)+1;
      }     

      return true;
    }

    arrInsertAfter(arr1, arr2, 2);

    alert(arr1);
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write such a function yourself yet? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: Remember that when inserting an element, the index of subsequent elements is incremented. So if inserting 3 elements after every second, you'd insert after 1, then 4, then 7.

Comment: Sorry, yes I made it, but forgot about saving current position and increase recieved `afterElement`... And result was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `forEach` on an array you are mutating in the callback function can be tricky to do. Here's a mutating approach using traditional loops and `splice` to add elements into the `a` array at specific index locations:

```js
function arrInsertAfter(a, b, after) {
  let j = 0;

  for (let i = after; i < a.length && j < b.length; i += after) {
    a.splice(i++, 0, b[j++]);
  }

  while (j < b.length) {
    a.push(b[j++]);
  }
}


const arr1 = ['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'white', 'magenta', 'cyan'];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

arrInsertAfter(arr1, arr2, 3);
console.log(arr1);
```

Here's a non-mutating version that preserves both parameters:

```js
function arrInsertAfter(a, b, after) {
  const res = a.slice(0);
  let j = 0;
  
  for (let i = after; i < res.length && j < b.length; i += after) {
    res.splice(i++, 0, b[j++]);
  }
  
  while (j < b.length) {
    res.push(b[j++]);
  }
    
  return res;
}


const arr1 = ['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'white', 'magenta', 'cyan'];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(arrInsertAfter(arr1, arr2, 2));
console.log(arrInsertAfter(arr1, arr2, 3));
```

And if you don't mind mutating `b`:

```js
const arrInsertAfter = (a, b, after) =>
  a.reduce((r, e, i) => 
    r.concat(i && i % after === 0 && b.length ? [b.shift(), e] : [e])
  , []).concat(b)
;


const arr1 = ['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'white', 'magenta', 'cyan'];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(arrInsertAfter(arr1, arr2.slice(), 2));
console.log(arrInsertAfter(arr1, arr2, 3));
```

Comment: Thx, but if I need to transform current array (arr1) can I use code like in UPD 2 of my question?

Comment: Your approach seems to work as well. I haven't tested these thoroughly with possible edge cases, but it doesn't seem like there should be too many such cases.

Answer (score 2):

This should do :)

```js
function arrInsertAfter(arr1, arr2, afterElement){
  result = [];
  for(var i = 1; arr2.length>0 || arr1.length>0;i++){
    if(arr1.length>0){
      result.push(arr1.shift());
    }
    if(i%afterElement==0 && arr2.length>0){
      result.push(arr2.shift());
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const arr1 = ['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'white', 'magenta', 'cyan'];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3];
result = arrInsertAfter(arr1, arr2, 3);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works when 'afterElement' value is fair enough to equally divide the first array. But Fails when this number can't divide the first array.

Comment: What do you mean? Even if 'afterElement' is greater than the size of any of the arrays, it works. It just places the second array's items at the end.   For example, with:

arr1 = ['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'white', 'magenta', 'cyan'];
 arr2 = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(arrInsertAfter(arr1,arr2,10)); 

You get ['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'white', 'magenta', 'cyan',1,2,3];

Comment: It's about the code before you edited your answer :). Your previous code will not work.

`function arrInsertAfter(arr1, arr2, afterElement){
    result = []
    for(var i = 1; arr2.length>0;i++){
        result.push(arr1.shift());
        if(i%afterElement==0){
            result.push(arr2.shift());
        }
    }
    return result;
}`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I thought the comment was after the edit!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a copy and splice the elements at the right position.

```js
function insertAfter(array1, array2, n)  {
    var temp = array1.slice();
    array2.forEach((v, i) => temp.splice((i + 1) * n + i, 0, v));
    return temp;
}

console.log(insertAfter(['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'white', 'magenta', 'cyan'], [1, 2, 3], 2));
console.log(insertAfter(['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'white', 'magenta', 'cyan'], [1, 2, 3], 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```